# How is .google a domain extension?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, domain-name

I just visited [blog.google](https://blog.google/). How does that work? Can organisations register their own domain extensions? If yes, what is the procedure and how expensive is that? If not, how did they achieve the blog domain then? Is there some networking trick to this that I am missing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain#Expansion_of_gTLDs - you'll need $185,000. These have been around nearly a decade now.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea. I'll start saving.

Comment: It is not an extension, it is a TLD: Top Level Domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request a generic top level domain (gTLD) from ICANN, it's quite costly, so only really large organisations have the cash to splurge on them for purely window dressing (there's no real technical benefit except maybe not relying on anybody to handle the TLD above your domain, but you're still reliant on the root zone). Others buy them to start selling domains under that gTLD, for example .cloud or .expert.

Country code top level domains (ccTLD) are another thing entirely, they are restricted to countries with an ISO 3166 code (with some exceptions).

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain

Comment: "You can request a generic top level domain (gTLD) from IANA," No. ICANN is in charge of TLDs, not IANA. IANA just does the technical stuff. ICANN opened applications for new TLDs in 2012, and hence Google asked for `.google`.

Comment: Good catch, don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that, I've amended my answer.